# Getting the sum according to customer id after pivoting

Tags: python, pandas

I want to get the total transaction of a customer after a pivoting. total should be the last row for customer data. For example customer, `12346.0` should have a total of `2.080`. see the image below
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can aggregate `sum` per `CustomerID` before pivoting, add `MultiIndex` and then join to `gdbf` by [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with sorting index by [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
df1 = pd.concat({'Total': df.groupby('CustomerID')[['UnitPrice']].sum()}).swaplevel(0,1)

df = pd.concat([gdbf, df1]).sort_index()
```